# Change opacity on all images ONLY except hovered one

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

here is my problem:

I have several pictures in a div, and I would like that when one of these pictures is hovered, all the other pictures drop in opacity. The problem is that I also have text in this div and I would like that when I hover on this text, the images are in opacity 1.

I tried to do this:

```css
.dimImagesHover:hover img {
  transition: 0.25s;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.dimImagesHover img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dimImagesHover">
  <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/0bf" alt="demo 1">
  <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/fb0" alt="demo 2">
  Here is a test ! When I hover this texte, I need to have my image in opacity 1.
  <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/bf0" alt="demo 3">
</div>
```

I've really tried a lot of things that don't work, so if you have a solution or advice don't hesitate and thanks in advance.

See you,
Léo

Comment: I suspect that you might be able to achieve what you're looking for with the sibling selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a little bit of JavaScript you can achieve that...

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dimImagesHover')

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onmouseover = function( e ){
    //check if it is an image that has been hovered
    // and add a class to parent
    if(e.target.tagName == 'IMG'){
      this.classList.add("imgHovered");
    }
  }
  elements[i].onmouseout = function( e ){
    this.classList.remove("imgHovered");
  }
}
```

```css
.dimImagesHover img {
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.dimImagesHover.imgHovered img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.dimImagesHover img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dimImagesHover">
  <img src="/" alt="demo 1">
  <img src="/" alt="demo 2">
  Here is a test ! When I hover this texte, I need to have my image in opacity 1.
  <img src="/" alt="demo 3">
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it works... see : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```css
.dimImagesHover:hover img {
  transition: 0.25s;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.dimImagesHover img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.dimImagesHover p:hover img {
  transition: 0.25s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dimImagesHover">
  <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/0bf" alt="demo 1">
  <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/fb0" alt="demo 2">
  <p>Here is a test ! When I hover this texte, I need to have my image in opacity 1.</p>
  <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/bf0" alt="demo 3">
</div>
```

This way, when you hover over the text (<p> tag), your images' opacity should be 1.